# Angular JS + Kinetic = dynamic chart on canvas

Tags: javascript, mvvm, angularjs, kineticjs

here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/paska27/L6VAe/5/

the code (so complains otherwise):

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MainCtrl"
ng-init="list = [
{name: 'Sergey', age: 26},
{name: 'Johan', age: 27},
{name: 'Iwan', age: 28}
];">
    <div id="box" ng-controller="PlaneCtrl"></div>       
    <input ng-model="currentItem.name" />
</div>

/** an extention of Kinetic shape (group, rect or what ever) **/
var Item = function(planeScope, item){
Kinetic.Group.call(this, {
    draggable: true
});

var self = this;

var text = new Kinetic.Text({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    text: item.name,
    fontSize: 20,
    fontFamily: 'Calibri',
    textFill: 'green',
    draggable: true
});

self.add(text);

self.name = text.getText();

self.on('dragstart', function(){
   planeScope.$parent.currentItem = self;
   planeScope.$apply();       
});
}
Kinetic.Global.extend(Item, Kinetic.Group);

var MainCtrl = function($scope){
    $scope.currentItem;
}

var PlaneCtrl = function($scope, $element){
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'box',
    width: 200,
    height: 200
}),
layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

angular.forEach($scope.list, function(item){
    item = new Item($scope, item);
    layer.add(item);
});

stage.add(layer);   
}
```

The task:

- i need to build some kind of a chart with items on it (just items, to
  keep it simple here)
- items could be any shape in the future (actually a Kinetic.Group of
  shapes)
- that's why i need a canvas
- items/shapes  need to be highly dynamic in the sense of updating any
  properties (text and x/y coords for now)
- that's why i need some so called MVVM framework

The question in general: how to build all this ?

The particular stuck in the realization i chose:
how to make a veiw --> model values update.
or in terms of the the libs in question:
how to update shapes properties (e.g. text of the Kinetic.Text obj)
from the ng-model directive ?

Many thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

This should be fairly straightforward to achieve using a custom chart directive. You can bind the `items` to the directive which then creates a canvas instance and renders your chart. Binding `items` to the directive will cause it to refresh every time the `items` data changes or vice versa.

To create the canvas instance simply initiate that part within the link function of the directive. i.e. pretty much all the code you have right now can be added to the link function. Just make sure you are passing the `items` object to the directive.

I show an example here of something similar using `three.js`:  [AngularJS Binding to WebGL / Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16054424/angularjs-binding-to-webgl-canvas/16876844#16876844)