# processing.js blank inside angularjs view

Tags: angularjs, processing

I am trying to include a processing Canvas inside a angularjs view.It works inside the index.html but not work  inside a view.Sample is given below.

https://plnkr.co/edit/3ZaLzswnnVcf71bwrrgp?p=preview

```
Home.html

        <div class="container">           
            <canvas data-processing-sources="hello.pde"  ></canvas>
            <a href="#/home"> Back</a>
        </div>


Index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/processing.js/1.4.1/processing.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

      <div ng-app="mainApp">
        <ng-view></ng-view>
      </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

ng-view is a directive from ngRoute. What you should do instead is just include your template:

```
<div ng-include="Home.html"></div>
```

If you want to use `ng-view` you must setup your app to work with [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute).

[Example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route)

Comment: Added it in main.js var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", ['ngRoute']);
     
    mainApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/home', {
                templateUrl: 'home.html',
                controller: 'StudentController'
            }) Does not work.Forgot to paste the code.Thanks for trying to help

Comment: No worries. If you can provide a plunker in the future we can just fix it there and give you a working answer

Comment: Added the sample code .Thanks once again https://plnkr.co/edit/3ZaLzswnnVcf71bwrrgp?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for the plunker. I see your problem but it seems to be specific to angulajs working with canvas which is outside of my expertise. [Kapil found a solution here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21037213/4775223) I hope that helps.